# Unity VideoPlayer and WebGLMovieTexture cant play two videos in a row

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to play videos in Unity WebGL in the browser, but having lots of problems.

I tried two different video players and none of them work fully.

The WebGLMovieTexture player works like this

```
public WebGLStreamingVideoPlugin _videoPlugin = new WebGLStreamingVideoPlugin("http://www.example.net/video.mp4");
_videoPlugin.Play();
```

Basically when you want to play a video you create a new instance and give it the URL like above, and it plays great!!

The problem is when you want to stop that video, and play a different video, it seems impossible because there is no way dispose of the first video because there is only a Stop() in the API, which stops the playback but it continues to stream the video data from the internet in the background.

There is no way to delete the instance because Destroy() cant be called since that WebGLMovieTexture is not derived from monodevelop, and C# does not seem to give a way to delete an object (how silly). Even setting it to null doesnt do it, it continues to stream the video in the background.

So if you create a new instance in order to play a different video, you end up with TWO video streams, and if you do it again to play a third, you end up with THREE, and so on, so quickly you can see how bad that will end up.

My question is how to dispose of or destroy the first WebGLMovieTexture player, or maybe tell it to stop streaming the first video and start playing a different one?

The second player I tried is the VideoPlayer for WebGL in Unity Version 5.6.0b4, with this one I can only get it to play a video if I hardcode the URL in the inspector, if I put the URL in code it doesn't play it in the browser.

```
    vPlayer = gameObject.GetComponent<UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer>();
    if (vPlayer.isPlaying) {
        Debug.Log("STOPPING PLAY");
        vPlayer.Stop();
    }
    vPlayer.url = url;
    vPlayer.isLooping = true;
    vPlayer.frame = 0;
    vPlayer.targetCameraAlpha = 1F;
    vPlayer.Prepare();
    vPlayer.Play();
```

And to get it to play a second video I suspect I will have the same problems as the other one.

Anybody have any ideas that can help me?

Comment: *"I can only get it to play a video if I hardcode the URL in the inspector, if i put the URL in code it doesnt play it in the browser."* Can you explain this and at the-same time, post the complete code of that? This is the only way to help you. Without that code, we can't tell what you are doing wrong.

Comment: If I paste the URL in the VideoPlayer component in the inspector (there is a place for the URL) then the video plays in the browser, but if I paste the SAME URL in the code, and leave the inspector version of the URL blank, it doesnt play in the browser.

Comment: Your code is not enough to help you. Use this url "http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" to test it. Replace it with whatever url you have in the Editor then take a screenshot of it and post it in your question. I want to see the settings. At the-same time, include the complete code. I feel like you are missing lots of stuff in your code but must see them before I can do anything.

Comment: I figured it out, I added extra javascript code inside the plugin to remove the WebGLMovieTexture and the stream. So it works now,.... i think! Thanks anyway!